# my mongodb local connection cant connect (mongodb version 6.0.8)

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, connection, localhost, bin

> const express = require("express");
> const app = express();
> const mongoose = require("mongoose");
>
> DB CONNECTION */
> mongoose.connect(
> "mongodb://localhost:27017/day1",
> {
> useNewUrlParser: true,
> useUnifiedTopology: true,
> },
> (err) => {
> if (!err) {
> console.log("Connected To DB!");
> else {
> console.log("Not Connected to db");
> }
> }
> );
>
> PORT 3000 */
> app.listen(3000, () => {
> console.log("Port 3000");
> });`

Hello i'm a beginner in backend development trying to advance study preparation for my upcomming college school year, What I don't understand is why it always showing that it is "not connected to db" on the terminal, is there anything I missed? what is the proper way of connecting it to db?

mongodb version 6.0.8

I watch some tutorial on youtube but most of them are using old versions of mongoDB,any help would be appreciated. :)

Comment: What is the error message?

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
// main js
const express = require("express");
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const app = express();

const start = async () => {
  try {
    await mongoose.connect(
      "mongodb://localhost:27017/day1"
    );
    app.listen(3000, () => console.log("Server started on port 3000"));
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
  }
};

start();
```

Please make sure you have mongodb server installed on your pc, running and listening on the indicated port (27017). And... format your code inside your questions :)